# Error : Parameter name not found, in Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, devart, parameterized-query

I am working in Asp.net with postgresql with devart dotconnect connection driver.
When i am executing a parmeterized query it is showing error,

> Parameter name not found

My code is below

```
Command = new Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand();
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", testmaster.TestName);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestShortName", testmaster.TestShortName);
DAF.Command.CommandText = @"Do $$
DECLARE newTestID INT;
BEGIN
"+"Insert into \"TestMaster\"(\"TestName\", \"TestShortName\", \"RCUID\", \"RCDate\", \"RCTime\") " + @"
    "+"values (:TestName, :TestShortName, 0, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME(0)) " + @"
    "+"RETURNING \"TestID\" INTO newTestID;"+@"
END$$;";

// Rest is execution code
```

What i am making a mistake here ?

Edit : I got on which code this message is occurring, it is not on insert command it is on returning command.

Comment: Are you sure that's the *entire* error message? Please copy and paste the full error/exception.

Comment: It is the full exception, no other detail it showing to me

Comment: Check my edit, the error was not on insert command it is on returning command

Comment: Exactly what line does the exception get thrown from? Is it in the "execution code"?

Comment: No, it is in sql command "Returnning"

Comment: It can't be - for a number of reasons. That's not an error PostgreSQL produces; `RETURNING` isn't a statement, it's just part of the `INSERT`; and most importantly because that's **just a string**. You don't run it. **Show the full exception stack trace please**, and line numbers that match up with the exception.

The code you show *cannot* produce that error without the "rest is execution code" bits you've left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parameter name not found` must be an error from the database driver. It's hard to be sure without the **full exception trace**, but at a guess I think that DevArt must require you to set the SQL text before attempting to set parameters.

e.g.

```
Command = new Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand();
Command.CommandText = "SELECT ...."; /* or whatever your SQL is */
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", testmaster.TestName);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestShortName", testmaster.TestShortName);
```

(I haven't used it, I'm just going by [the examples in some of the docs](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html), which while they refer to Oracle parameters seem much the same for the basics.)

---

However, it's also possible that DevArt can't parse the `DO` block and `$$` quoting. To confirm that, try:

```
Command = new Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand();
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", testmaster.TestName);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestShortName", testmaster.TestShortName);
Command.CommandText = "Insert into \"TestMaster\"(\"TestName\", \"TestShortName\", \"RCUID\", \"RCDate\", \"RCTime\") values (:TestName, :TestShortName, 0, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME(0)) RETURNING \"TestID\" INTO newTestID;";
```

If this works, but the version in the `DO` block doesn't, then it's probably because DevArt can't parse the `DO` block or its `$$` quoting to find parameters.

You might need to use an SQL function instead (assuming you're trying to do more after the first statement, otherwise there'd be no point using a `DO` block at all). Then call the function in a separate statement. e.g. first execute this SQL without any parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(testname text, testshortname text) returns void AS $$
DECLARE
    newTestID INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT into "TestMaster"("TestName", "TestShortName", "RCUID", "RCDate", "RCTime")
    VALUES (testname, testshortname, 0, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME(0))
    RETURNING TestID INTO newTestID;

    -- whatever you want to do with newTestID here
END$$;
```

*then* run another statement to call the function, like:

```
Command = new Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand();
Command.CommandText = "SELECT myfunc(:TestName, :TestShortName)";
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestName", testmaster.TestName);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestShortName", testmaster.TestShortName);
```

to call it.

There's no `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` so you'll have to `DROP FUNCTION` afterwards if you don't want to keep and re-use it.

Comment: Yes, i got it the parser, does not pars do block, so that error occurring. Now i am going to try function

Comment: can you help me how to use out parameter in function and calling it from C# code

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi If you have something new, *post a new question* please. This time please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first, so you can provide a clearer question that requires less guesswork.